# How to iterate all images from a pdf file with itext 7?

Tags: image, pdf, iteration, itext7

I want to resize  images in pdf file with itext 7. But the backgroud images cannot be obtained when I iterate all XObjects.
My implemented code  is below.

```
def getAllImages(xObjects: PdfDictionary):ListBuffer[PdfName] = {
    var list=ListBuffer[PdfName]()
    xObjects.entrySet().forEach(obj=>if(obj.getValue.isStream) {
      val stream=xObjects.getAsStream(obj.getKey)
      val subtype=stream.get(PdfName.Subtype)
      if(subtype.toString.equals("/Image")){
        list += obj.getKey
      }else if(subtype.toString.equals("/Form")){
       getAllImages(obj.getValue.asInstanceOf[PdfDictionary])
      }
    })
    list
  }


  def removeWaterMarker(pdf: File, pdfnew: File, bfimgs: Array[BufferedImage]): Unit = {
    val pdfDoc: PdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdf), new PdfWriter(pdfnew))
    for( i<- 1 to pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages){
      val page=pdfDoc.getPage(i)
      val pageDict: PdfDictionary = page.getPdfObject
      val resources: PdfDictionary = pageDict.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources)
      val xObjects: PdfDictionary = resources.getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject)
      val images=getAllImages(xObjects)
      resize(images)
    }
```

Is there something wrong? How to iterate all images from a pdf file with itext 7?

Comment: It's scala code. And the funciton of resize() was not implemented.

Comment: Images may also be defined in pattern resources, annotation resources, or inline in content streams.